# Unable to connect to the Azure SQL Database from AWS Container

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, amazon-ecs

Previously, We had deployed a Azure Infrastructure with SQL Server in one VNet and deployed another AWS Infrastructure in VPC. So we connected both Azure VNet and AWS VPC with S2S VPN. So, we deployed APIs into AWS container and tried inserting some data into the SQL server through API. But was getting error there. Attaching the error below. And we deployed a AZure VM in same Vnet and tried connecting to SQL server using Private IP of SQLserevr with SQL Authentication. Attaching the error screenshots and error message for reference.

[image]

Error message:-
"<!doctype html>  500 Internal Server Error

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application".

Note:- We created service endpoints for SQL server and whitelisted all the required IPs in SQL server firewall.

So, do we need to modify any configurations on Azure SQL server side or on Containers side?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you please provide your approach?

Comment: Approach means? Could please elaborate this?